# Tomcat 7 Persistent Session Manager prematurely loads from Store

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are attempting to configure the [dynamodb session manager](https://github.com/aws/aws-dynamodb-session-tomcat) for tomcat 7 in an elasticbeanstalk environment running a single server.

We can see the session data being periodically backed up to dynamodb but occasionally the old session data (for the same session) is being loaded back out of dynamodb. In our application this manifests itself by loading the previous item you were looking at (the item is stored on the session). The JSESSIONID cookie stays the same and the client keeps the same session. If we turn the session manager off, the issue is resolved.

Here is the contents of our context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Manager
    className="com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.sessionmanager.DynamoDBSessionManager"
    Table="SessionTable"
    RegionId="eu-west-1"/>
</Context>
```

We've tried setting maxIdleBackup and maxIdleSwap to high numbers as defined in the [tomcat 7 docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) to no avail.

If we set maxIdleBackup and maxIdleSwap to zero then the error is reduced because the session data is backed up to dynamodb more often, but this doesn't solve the issue.

What is causing tomcat to load the session data back from the Store? My understanding was that it should only be loaded from the store if it is not available at all (i.e client hits a different tomcat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we resorted to using the [JDBCStore](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) which does not have this issue. I hope to come back to this problem in the future given more time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you suffer from the async nature (and the implicit need for sticky sessions) of the implementation as noted in [issue #6](https://github.com/aws/aws-dynamodb-session-tomcat/issues/6)

If you are not using sticky sessions I recommend you go for the [Redis approach](https://github.com/jcoleman/tomcat-redis-session-manager) which is synchronous

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are using sticky sessions and still see the issue when using a single server. I've tried debugging the code but am unable to pinpoint the issue. For some reason, the session is loaded from the database before the current version is backed up.

Like you say, it could be the asynchronous nature of the backup, but our application is mostly form based.

Comment: In the end we resorted to using the built in JDBCStore which does not have this issue.